# duedate counter works in Chrome but not Firefox NaN error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, firefox

Firefox somehow is not working when it comes to this js code. However it works fine in Chrome.

- Does this have to do with `document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;` ?
- Do i need to parseInt? idk how to do that if i have to do that.. haha
- The main question is how to get this to work in firefox??

```html
 <div id="dueDate-counter">
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>days</td>
       <td>hrs</td>
       <td>mns</td>
       <td>secs</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td id="days"></td>
       <td id="hours"></td>
       <td id="minutes"></td>
       <td id="seconds"></td>
      </tr>

     </table> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
      function countdown() {
       var now = new Date();
       var eventDate = new Date("<%= reservation.due_date %>");
       <%= puts "here is reservation !!!!!!!" %>;
       <%= puts "#{reservation.due_date}" %>;
       var currentTime = now.getTime();
       var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

       var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

       var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
       var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
       var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
       var d = Math.floor(h / 24);

       h %= 24;
       m %= 60;
       s %= 60;

       h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
       m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
       s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

       document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
       document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

       document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
       document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
       document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;

        setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
         }

        countdown();

     </script>

    </div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is more flexible than other browsers with Date objects. Ensure your `due_date` and `eventDate` are the same format with `console.log`. getTime() returns milliseconds, so your `reservation.due_date` must be in milliseconds too.

Comment: how could i convert this datetime into milliseconds?? . in the js script how could i take reservation.due_date and convert it in milliseconds? I thought i already did that with the `.getTime()`

Comment: You can get the parts of the date from `due_date` such as year, month, day, minutes and then do `var eventDate = new Date(year, month, day)`